# How long will Microsoft support Windows XP Professional?

Tags: windows-xp, security, updates

I am using Windows XP Professional for some specific software programs. Now I read in the latest German CT-Magazin that Microsoft will fix big security problems until 2014.
At microsoft.com is spoken about "mainstream" support (for SP3) until April 2012. Extended support until April 2017, but for "commercial customers" only (and what am I?).

Does anyone know more about it?

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft documents their product support lifecycle here: http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifepolicy

which includes a link to this page: http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifeselect

which lets you answer the same question for all of their products.

Answer (score 3):

Commercial customers are Corporations or other large businesses that can afford to purchase extended support contracts > (Essential and Premier) I doubt the majority of end users can afford this.

From link posted by David Statton   http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifepolicy

> Security updates will be available **through the end of the Extended Support phase** (five years of Mainstream Support plus five years of the Extended Support) at no additional cost for most products. Security updates will be posted on the Microsoft Update Web site during both the Mainstream and the Extended Support phase.

[Extended Support End Date for XP Pro is 4-8-2014](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?LN=en-us&x=9&y=11&p1=3223), after that most XP users will no longer get security updates via windows updates, it is time to abandon XP after this date for security reasons.

Microsoft can change this policy or dates at any time if they wish, which they did for Windows 98 years back due to Corporate outcry, I doubt this will happen for XP but who knows.
.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft won't continue supporting XP after another year. However, if there is a critical update needed to XP (such as to prevent a worm from spreading) then XP will then be updated. So in a sense, Microsoft will continue to support XP in a way until it's market share falls to such a number like 1%.