# Will I still be able to activate Windows XP after support ends?

Tags: windows-xp, license, windows-activation

I read through [How long will Microsoft support Windows XP Professional?](https://superuser.com/questions/246544/how-long-will-microsoft-support-windows-xp-professional) but could find no mention of how long Microsoft will continue to allow/support activations of XP for, using internet or over the phone.

Comment: One assumes they will keep the XP activation servers going, since they don't want a deluge of phone calls, but they can do anything they want, time will tell, there is no official word from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about over the Internet, but the phone-activation option uses one number for all Microsoft products, and the last time I needed to use it it didn't ask which product the user was trying to activate.  It therefore seems reasonable that the phone activation option will remain as long as Microsoft allows activation of *any* of their products over the phone.

Comment: Doesn't it ask for the product key? That would identify the product and enable them to selectively permit or deny activation.  Not saying they would or wouldn't, but it seems quite feasible.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to active Windows XP a few days ago via the phone support.